# How to get table in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a component with a table. I want to check if the first element of every row of the table equals the current week day, and then print it out, so here's what I've done

```
import React from 'react';

class Info extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.checkDay = this.checkDay.bind(this);
    }

    checkDay() {
        let now = new Date();
        let myTab = document.getElementById('myTable');
        console.log(myTab);
        let days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
        let today = days[now.getDay()];
        for (let i = 0; i < myTab.rows.length; i++) {
            let content = myTab.rows.item(i).cells;
            if(content.item(0).innerHTML===today) {
                console.log(today);
            }
        }
    }

    
    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <table className="table" id="myTable">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Monday</td>
                            <td>8:00 - 20:00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tuesday</td>
                            <td>8:00 - 20:00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Wednesday</td>
                            <td>8:00 - 20:00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Thursday</td>
                            <td>8:00 - 20:00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Friday</td>
                            <td>8:00 - 20:00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Saturday</td>
                            <td>8:00 - 17:00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Sunday</td>
                            <td>closed</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
             </table>
             {this.checkDay()}
        </div>
        );
    }
  };
  
  export default Info;
```

Except this doesn't work because the table seems to be a NULL. I've also tried giving that ID to the tbody, same problem. Also I'm not sure the function works as it is, so if anybody could also point out any error it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using React incorrectly, so check the docs and some tutorials.

You can create a function that will compare your values, etc. and run it for every row (you should return a value in my example):

```
checkDay(value) {
  // checking your value and then return a new value
  return value;
}
```

and the row:

```
<tr>
    <td>{checkDay("Monday")}</td>
    <td>8:00 - 20:00</td>
</tr>
```

What is more elegant, you can also create an array of objects which contain day info:

```
const week = [{day: "Monday", hours: "8:00 - 20:00"}, {day: "Tuesday", hours: "8:00 - 20:00"}] // and so on...
```

and then use the map function inside your code:

```
<tbody>
{
    week.map((day, i) => {
     yourFunctionThatChecksDay(day);
    
     return <tr key={i}><td>{day.day}</td><td>{day.hours}</td></tr>
    }
}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use react ref to get reference of DOM element, check the official documentation:
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html